# No transaction when using Spring websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-websocket

I have configured a websocket with @MessageMapping annotation as usual. It works perfectly but when I call to some method surrounded with @Transactional and I try to executed some updated over the database I get an error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query.
```

It seems the transactional manager it is not working in this case. However, when this same method is invoked from a Rest controller everything goes well. Anybody knows what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the XML config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

with JAVA config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
   @Autowired
   private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
   }
}
```

and it works.